# How to Send message From android device to PC USING WIFI

Tags: android, sockets, wifi, send

I have a server on a PC (using socket).
I want to send data (a message) from android to a PC server using Wi-Fi.
What should I use?
Socket on  OR Wi-Fi direct? (on android).
I've been looking for.
Including in this forum.
All answers that are found are associated with the local address. Or useless tips and links to a slightly different topic.
And I have to use Wi-Fi.
Help, please.
Can anybody give an example?
By the way, can I send using sockets or to use a special Wi-Fi interface on both devices? (PC and android).
Sorry for my bad English.
I would like to get help.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LAN by WiFi. Your computer and Android must be in same wifi.

In the computer, make a server app with a socket listening.

In Android put IP Address of the PC and create a socket.

Comment: i know it.But what tools to use.Just socket or special wifi direct(interface).it would be better if I had an example

Comment: You are confused. You always need socket, wifi, wifi direct or bluetooth is irrelevant, you need socket to comunication. Search tutorials of "tcp socket in java"

Comment: And if I want to send between computers using WiFi, will also work on a socket? 
I heard that for this purpose use like NativeWIFI.

Comment: theory is a theory 
About sockets I also know a lot, but for some reason I can not bind to WiFi and spolzovat sockets. Could give an example?

Comment: until you give advice that can give a child Googling

Comment: Everything. 
Problem solved. 
My router did not give ip address of the machine. I put static on the tablet.